# How to solve Volterra's integral equation of second kind with numerical solution

Tags: numerical-methods, integral-equations

The problem occurs to me when I tried to solve
\begin{align}E(x)=1+2(1-x)^2\int_{x}^{1}(1-t)E\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)dt\end{align}
with $E(1)=1$ and  $\lim_{x\to 0^+}E(x) \to +\infty$.

I'd like to find $E(1/2)$.

But I have no idea how to solve it with Mathematica or Matlab.

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Mathematica, you could try to apply the fixed-point and interpolation technique in this article:

http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i2/IntegralEquations.html

Comment: Thank you! I have tried the iteration, but when f(x) tends to zero, it's hard to interpolate the function, is there any useful idea to solve this problem?